# What is the difference between Web sockets per instance and IP connections?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

What is the difference between Web sockets per instance and IP connections?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#managing-limits

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket protocol enables a full duplex communication between a server and a client **over a long running TCP connection**. In a simple word, WebSocket uses TCP/IP to communicate.